# Getting the mapping for a permutation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have two arrays where one is a permutation of the other:

```
A = [2 1 5 3 7]
B = [7 2 1 3 5]
```

with no repetitions in either array.

How can I obtain the permutation mapping between both?

E.g. `A->B` should be:

```
[2, 3, 5, 4, 1]
```

which means:

```
A(1) -> B(2)
A(2) -> B(3)
A(3) -> B(5)
A(4) -> B(4)
A(5) -> B(1)
```

### Update:

Is there a **fast** vectorized solution that does not use `ismember` ? In my experience, `ismember` tends to be slow for very large arrays.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the elements of `A` and `B` are unique?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this:

```
[i a] = sort(A);
[i b] = sort(B);
mapping = b(a)
```

Comment: Speed is about 2x better than `ismember`.

Comment: Somebody else already did all the hard work optimizing `sort`.  :)

Comment: [Apparently](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15K1B/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-15K1B) it is just a quick sort (so we know who "somebody" is). BTW the performance ratio is about the same across >5 orders of magnitude of array sizes.

Comment: You may get speedup if you sort both vectors in the same call.  I believe some versions of Matlab do a better job multithreading in this case?  Depending on your hardware, you might also get significantly better speed by sorting in-place, which would require a Mex function.

Answer (score 7):

Use `ismember`.

```
[~,idx] = ismember(A,B);
```

The vector `idx` will contain indices such that `B(idx) == A`.

Note that `ismember` finds the *highest* indices.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use knnsearch, but for not repeated members in both a and b

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i=1:size(B)
C(:,i) = [i find(B==A(i))]
end
```

Comment: This will cause problems if more than one element of `B` is equal to an element of `A`.

Comment: and is less efficient than other solutions