# Is there a built-in function in Matlab to determine if a permutation is even or odd?

Tags: matlab, permutation

> *Variants of this question have been crossposted to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379809/is-there-a-name-for-this-function-parity-of-a-finite-sequence) and [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7053/how-can-i-compute-whether-a-sequence-is-an-even-or-odd-permutation-of-an-increas). Additional answers may be found at these other sites.*

This question is related to that posed at [Getting the mapping for a permutation in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899539/getting-the-mapping-for-a-permutation-in-matlab#new-answer) .  The title pretty much says it all.  I would like to know if there is a built-in function in Matlab for determining if a permutation represented by a vector is even or odd.  For example, [2  1 4  3 5] is an even permutation of the identity permutation [1 2 3 4 5] because it requires an even number of swaps to get from one vector to the other.  This seems like the kind of thing that people might want to do often and that there might be a built-in function for.  People have posted quite long Matlab files on the Web to accomplish this.  If I could get Matlab to give me a permutation *matrix*, then I could take the determinant of that matrix, but I haven't figured out how to do that, nor do I know if there's a quick way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in function for this. But it has a simple and efficient solution:
Your sign should be the determinant of the permutation matrix for the vector.

```
a = [2 1 4 3 5];
I = speye(length(a));
sign = det(I(:,a));
```

Comment: great!  I've never used "speye" before.  Someone at Computational Science Stack Exchange Beta posted a slightly longer solution that required a for loop.

Comment: speye is not of much use for this example but is quite handy if you have high dimensions and you're working in sparse domains.

Comment: The other answer used "eye" and "numel" and appears to be basically the same.  I have used : before but never quite like this.  There are Matlab guys at work I can about how this works.

Answer (score 2):

Funny you ask about a permutation matrix.  Is this sufficient?

```
x = [2 1 4 3 5];
y = eye(numel(x));
evenodd = det( y(:,x) );
```

The value of `evenodd` is `1` if even or `-1` if odd.

Comment: great!  I've never used a trick like "y(:,x)" before.  Someone at Computational Science Stack Exchange Beta posted a slightly longer solution that required a for loop.  Someone here posted a solution of the same length that appeared before yours, and I can only accept one solution.