# Find all mappings between two binary vectors of same size?

Tags: matlab, permutation, combinatorics

This is very similar to this question

[Getting the mapping for a permutation in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899539/getting-the-mapping-for-a-permutation-in-matlab)

I am wondering how to find all possible mappings between two binary vectors where the entries can repeat and are either 1 or 0.

For instance, find all mappings between these two binary vectors

[0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]
and
[1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]

Comment: matlab/octave would probably be the easiest to test.  I can translate to C++.

Comment: Hi Dietmar, as far as what I have tried...the brute force method I can think of would be to generate all possible permutations/mappings of the input 8-bit vector and then check the output for the mappings that match the output vector.  This would work, but it would not scale well, ideally I would like to run this on say two 32-bit vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution finds all the places in B where zeroes can go (T0), and where ones can go (T1). Then it loops through all those permutations, producing each mapping.

```
A = [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0];
B = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1];

l = length(A);

T0 = perms(find(B==0)); % all targets for zeroes
T1 = perms(find(B==1)); % all targets for ones

s0 = find(A==0); % source of zeroes
s1 = find(A==1); % source of ones

nT0 = size(T0,1);
nT1 = size(T1,1);

q = zeros(1,l);

for i = 1:nT0
    t0 = T0(i,:); % current target for zeroes
    for j = 1:nT1
        t1 = T1(j,:); % current target for ones
        q(s0) = t0;
        q(s1) = t1
        % q has a mapping
    end
end
```

Comment: Awesome guys!  Thanks, these both work perfectly, I would accept both, but I guess I have to pick the matlab or C++ solution.  I would upvote both, but I don't yet have enough points to be able to upvote, haha

Answer (score 2):

Brute-force approach: generate all possible mappings (permutations), and keep only those for which the image of the first vector is the second vector:

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0]; %// initial vector
y = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]; %// image vector
maps = perms(1:numel(x)); %// each row is a possible mapping
valid = all(bsxfun(@eq, x(maps), y), 2); %// 1 for mappings that map x to y
maps = maps(valid,:); %// keep only valid mappings
```

For your example vectors, this gives 720 mappings (out of  40320 possibilities) that transform `x` into `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You may do the matching for each part and combine the result.

Following may help (C++ code done before tag has been removed):

```
// print the combination of the two partial mappings.
// So that print one full mapping.
void print(
    const std::vector<bool>& flags,
    const std::vector<std::size_t>& zeros,
    const std::vector<std::size_t>& ones)
{
    auto it0 = zeros.begin();
    auto it1 = ones.begin();
    for (const auto& b : flags) {
        if (b) {
            std::cout << *it1++ << " ";
        } else {
            std::cout << *it0++ << " ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// Display all full mappings.
void displayMapping(const std::vector<bool>& orig, const std::vector<bool>& target) {
    // same number of one
    assert(std::accumulate(orig.begin(), orig.end(), 0)
        == std::accumulate(target.begin(), target.end(), 0));
    // same number of zero
    assert(orig.size() == target.size());
    std::vector<std::size_t> zeros;
    std::vector<std::size_t> ones;
    // dispatch indexes for partial mapping 
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != target.size(); ++i) {
        if (target[i]) {
            ones.push_back(i);
        } else {
            zeros.push_back(i);
        }
    }

    do {
        do {
            print(orig, zeros, ones);
        } while (std::next_permutation(zeros.begin(), zeros.end()));
    } while (std::next_permutation(ones.begin(), ones.end()));
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/QBnnpf)